# SQL is it possible to have multiple subqueries in From clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have 2 tables.

the first one would be the **bill**:

| id | total | client_code | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 1 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | 20 | 1 | 2022-02-01 |
| 3 | 20 | 3 | 2022-03-01 |

the second would be the **product** (for a bill):

| bill_id | category | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Electronic | 2 |
| 1 | Food | 5 |
| 1 | Food | 3 |
| 2 | Food | 10 |
| 2 | Food | 10 |
| 3 | Food | 10 |
| 3 | Food | 10 |

What I want to get with my query is the average spending by a client for each month over the last 4 months for example.

my query right now is looking like this for the first 2 months and it works, I get the result I want:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(AVG(first.total),0),
  COALESCE(AVG(second.total),0)
FROM
  (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-02-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-03-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as first),
  (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-02-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-03-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as second)
```

but as soon as I get to 3 months it doesn't anymore:

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(AVG(first.total),0),
  COALESCE(AVG(second.total),0),
  COALESCE(AVG(third.total),0)
FROM
  (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-02-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-03-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as first),
  (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-02-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-03-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as second),
  (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-03-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-01-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as three)
```

Is there a rule that keeps me from having more than two subqueries inside my from clause?
If so is there an other way of doing this? My real problem is for 12 month actually not 4. I already have a working solution but performance wise it's bad, that is why I am trying this.

My working solution is looking like that:

```
(SELECT 
  COALESCE(AVG(req.total),0)
FROM
   (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-02-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-03-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as req)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
  COALESCE(AVG(req.total),0)
FROM
   (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-03-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-04-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as req)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
  COALESCE(AVG(req.total),0)
FROM
   (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-04-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-05-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as req)
UNION ALL
(SELECT 
  COALESCE(AVG(req.total),0)
FROM
   (SELECT
     SUM(p.total) as total
   FROM
     bill b
     INNER JOIN product p one b.id = p.bill_id
   WHERE
     b.created_at >= '2022-05-01' AND b.created_at < '2022-06-01' AND
     p.category = 'FOOD'
   GROUP BY
     p.client_code) as req)
```

Comment: why dont you use a simple group by on month ?

Comment: there is no created_at column in your example

Comment: No rule that I know of (per your question). But this probably isn't the best way to write this query either... It looks like the reason it "doesn't work" is you you haven't added the third item at the top -- `COALESCE(AVG(third.total),0)`

Comment: @Steven I omitted the created_at from the table because I only wanted to put the relevant date in the table, I thought the created_at was self explanatory

Comment: @topsail my bad I edited that to make it right, it is in my actual code though and it still doesn't work. I am open to another way of doing this

Comment: if you call the column in your example, you should add it in your table description. You code needs to be runable. And with this missing column, someone can probably provide a better query

Comment: There is no problem with any number of  sub-selects. You are getting an error not because of the third select but your reference COALESCE(AVG(third),0)  is completely invalid. Change that to match your reference the same as alias first and second. Namely: `COALESCE(AVG(third.total),0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (but I'm pretty sure I don't have the right way of getting months, years in postgres - you will have to fix that!)

```
SELECT
    A.client_code,
    avg(A.total) as AvgMonthlyTotal
FROM
(
    SELECT
       SUM(p.total) as total,
       month(b.created_at),
       p.client_code
    FROM
        bill b
    INNER JOIN product p
    on b.id = p.bill_id
    WHERE 
        p.Category = 'FOOD'
        and year(b.created_at) = 2022 
    GROUP BY 
        month(b.created_at)
        p.client_code
) A
GROUP BY A.client_code;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I see how you are doing this but the result I need is the average of the SUM(p.total) by client for each month. In better terms this would give me the average of total by month (If I add and avg in there) and what I need is the average of spendings by clients per month

Comment: Gotcha - I updated the answer - it is still pseudo-sql though really :) There is probably a better way but this is still going to be a big improvement on the original I think.